# Pass the name of a member from a class as a parameter to a function

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to do a very generic widget, to which i can give whatever object i want. In this widget, depending on the object i gave it, i'm gonna need to represent the object with a text widget. My problem is that the objects that i'm gonna user doesn't have all the same members name. Let's say in one case i'm gonna give the object Carrot, in this case i want to show the member named "name" in the text widget, but in another case i can give it the object Template, in this case i want to display the member "code". They're always gonna be string type. So in the widget, the part 'titre' would be replaced by what i want to display.

```
class DialogDropdown extends StatelessWidget with TextStylesHelper{
  final SizingInformation _sizeInfo;
  final Function _onChanged;
  final List _objectList;

  DialogDropdown(
    this._sizeInfo,
    this._onChanged,
    this._objectList,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var item = _objectList[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('titre', style: labelTextStyle(_sizeInfo.scaleFactor),),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context, item);
              },
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                thickness: 1.5,
                height: _sizeInfo.screenSize.height / 40,
              ),
          itemCount: _objectList.length,
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

All objects should have the toString() override implemented and show something meaningful. You could also implement an abstract base class and force all derived classes to implement e.g. name property. Your Widget should change to a template `class WhatEver<T extends NameProvider> extends StatelessWidget with TextStylesHelper{ {`

The callback `onChange` have to be also templatized
`typedef void OnChange<T extends NameProvider>(T newValue);`.
The same is true for the `List<T extends NameProvider>`